# Auto increment a non PK column if null (MySQL 5.5)

Tags: mysql

I have a table User

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `clientid`  ???
);
```

I'd like `clientid` to be either specified (many familly member can have the same `clientid`) or `auto_incremented` from the max clientid if not specified.

I tried different type but get an error : *Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key*.

I'd like to keep the query and the database as simple as possible (not use trigger or complex queries if that's possible as they are not supported by my ORM)

Answer (score 3):

Your data model seems off. If you have a column called `clientid`, then I would expect you table have a table called `Clients` (my tables are usually plural names). The table `Clients` would have an auto-incremented id. Your above table would refer to it using a foreign key relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
    clientid int not null auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  userid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  clientid int,
  constraint fk_user_client foreign key (clientid) references clients(clientid)
);
```

Comment: This is a clean solution but to keep requests simple and for performances reason I'd like to keep all the data in one table

Comment: @IggY . . . A muddled data model usually leads to (more) muddled code.  There is basically no performance hit in having a few joins to connect different entities, particularly if you have indexes and the volume of data is not really big (say in the millions of rows).